Proof for Heine Borel
$\textbf{Theorem: }$ A subset $K\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is compact $\iff$ each open cover has a finite subcover.
$\textbf{Proof: }$ Now I am quite comfortable with the proof for ($\Rightarrow$) since we can prove it for intervals and then it follows for any general $K \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ since we can cover with intervals.
I am more unsure about the ($\Leftarrow$) but here is my attempt, please correct me or inform me if it lacks rigour in some aspects.
First note that $K$ being compact in $\mathbb{R}^n \iff K$ is closed and bounded. Let us first show that it is bound by way of contradiction. So we assume it is unbounded and it has a finite subcover for any open cover.
Now take $\mathbf{x}\in K$, consider the balls $B(\mathbf{x}, j) = \{ \mathbf{y} \in\mathbb{R}^n; |\mathbf{x} - \mathbf{y}| = j,\quad j \in \mathbb{N} \}$. The union of all these balls will be an open cover. But since it is unbounded $\forall j\in \mathbb{N}$ $\exists \mathbf{x_i}\in K$ s.t. $|\mathbf{x} - \mathbf{x_i}| > j$. So there is no finite subcover, and hence, there is a contradiction $\Rightarrow\Leftarrow$.
Now show that it is bounded. Note that sequentially compact $\iff$ compact (closed and bounded). Suppose $K$ is not closed. Let $(a_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}\subset K$ and $a_n \to \mathbf{a} \in\mathbb{R}^n$. We want to show $\mathbf{a}\in K$. Suppose $\mathbf{a} \notin K$ then $\mathbf{a} \in \partial K$ otherwise the sequence is not in $K$. Now consider an open cover as the union of the closed balls' compliments $ \overline{B(\mathbf{a}, \frac{1}{n})}^{\smash{\vphantom{\overline{B(\mathbf{a}, \frac{1}{n})}}}\mathrm{c}}, n\in \mathbb{N} \setminus \{0\}$. Now $\forall N\in\mathbb{N}$ $\exists n\in\mathbb{N}\quad$ $n>N$ s.t. $a_n\in {\overline{B(\mathbf{a}, \frac{1}{n})}}$ but $a_n \notin \overline{B(\mathbf{a}, \frac{1}{n})}^{\smash{\vphantom{\overline{B(\mathbf{a}, \frac{1}{n})}}}\mathrm{c}}$ hence again we can't omit a single cover and thus no finite subcover $\Rightarrow\Leftarrow$.
I am mostly concerned with the second part ($K$ is closed) can I use that the limit point of the sequence is not in $K$ or should I approach it in some easier way, as it appears notationally unrigorous.

The definition of compact is that each open cover has a finite subcover. Seems to me what you’re trying to prove is that compactness implies closed and bounded?

@DavidGao In our course the definition was closed and bounded that is why I am trying to prove that  each open cover has a subcover $\implies$ closed and bounded.

I think it is really hard to read your proof. Might wanna read one proof from your text and try to simplify. I found one proof https://www.math.ucla.edu/~greene/Why%20Closed%20Bounded%20Sets%20in%20Rn%20are%20Compact.pdf. Also, I didn't get why you assumed K to be open since closed and open are not opposite things. (assuming that was for contradiction). Also, I don't know but maybe first direction is not that easy, try checking that too if yw

@MahammadYusifov Thanks, I will take a look at it, indeed you are correct that closed and open are not opposite, I fixed that.

I’m voting to close this question because it does not meet the standards of the tag "solution-verification" for posts looking for feedback or verification of a proposed solution. "Is this proof correct?" is too broad or missing context. Instead, the question must identify precisely which step in the proof is in doubt, and why so. This should not be the only tag for a question, and should not be used to circumvent site policies regarding duplicate questions.

@PaulFrost I think I state that I am in doubt of the $\Leftarrow$ direction of the proof. Which I show how I do. Not sure how to put it otherwise..

@TeodorasPaura Then I suggest that you edit your question and explain where you have doubts and why.

@PaulFrost clarified.

There are different ways to proving closedness, but as far as I can tell your argument is basically right, minus minor typos.
